# Cannot open file cua in second instance of Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

i get the following error when trying to open a second instance of emacs:

File error: "Cannot open load file" , "cua"

I guess I don't HAVE to open another instance of emacs (that is the beauty after all), I was just trying to keep some things separated (specifically work - like code and debug - and play - like news).

Would there be any reason I could not open two instances of emacs if I use cua.el?

Comment: Where are you getting cua.el?

Comment: the path to my cua.el file? or where did i get it from the web? (my home directory with my .emacs to the former... and i dont remember to the latter...)

Comment: correction: the file says it is version 2.10 and i got it from http://www.cua.dk/

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on windows and I activated cua (built in version) in a window then opened a new instance of emacs and it worked. Maybe upgrade?

Comment: yes, definately the best option. i did that at home to solve this problem. unfortunately, at work that is not an option right now, so i am searching for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the problem, so i figured i should post in case anyone else is seeing the same thing.

it turns out, it has NOTHING to do with a second instance of emacs. i cant even open a SINGLE instance (i just had been running one instance since before i saw the problem i guess... only noticed this time because of a shutdown).

i changed the following and the problem disappeared. in my .emacs file:

(require 'cua)
(CUA-mode t)

TO

(load-file "cua.el") ;; or if you compiled it (load-file "cua.elc")
(CUA-mode t)

this did the trick for me... although i am not sure why.

thanks to all who commented.

PS - i am using emacs 21.3.1, so i do have an older version. if any readers have the option, justinhj's comment above (about upgrading) is probably the easiest answer. CUA is built into version 22 and above i believe.